# Java application progress bar color changed while running in Matlab

Tags: java, matlab, swing, jprogressbar, matlab-java

I am applying a JAVA application with Matlab. When I test my program in Eclipse, everything is fine, the progress bar is showing in desired color. But when I call this JAVA application(through jar file) from Matlab. The progress bar is all green, I am struggling in this situation, I do not know where is the problem as everything is fine when I run it without Matlab.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keNhm.png)

```java
JProgressBar progressBarFirstSubjectNeuralSignal;
UIDefaults defaultsFirstSubject = new UIDefaults();


defaultsFirstBar.put("ProgressBar[Enabled].foregroundPainter", new 
CustomPainter(Color.RED));

defaultsFirstBar.put("ProgressBar[Enabled+Finished].foregroundPainter", new 
CustomPainter(Color.RED));

progressBarFirstBarSignal.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides.InheritDefaults", Boolean.TRUE);   
progressBarFirstBarSignal.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", defaultsFirstSubject);
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: You can provide a custom UI for your progress bar based on the `BasicProgressBarUI`, which paints using your color and ignores all UI settings that may be performed by Matlab.